# How to use loadAsync for TextureResource

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, realitykit

I have a problem with using loadAsync for TextResource class. It returns `LoadRequest<TextureResource>` but I also don't know how I can handle that. The documentation for those objects is very poor, and also I couldn't find any tutorial for that. Anyone can solve it? Thanks!

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: imageFilePath)
let texture = try! TextureResource.loadAsync(contentsOf: url).result!.get()
var material = SimpleMaterial()
material.baseColor = MaterialColorParameter.texture(texture)
let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: paintingMesh, materials: [material])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so I solved that issue, and I'd like to share the answer!
So basically we have to use Combine framework to handle that async request
There is a code example and remember to **add import Combine**

```
        var textureRequest: AnyCancellable? = nil
        textureRequest = TextureResource.loadAsync(contentsOf: url).sink { (error) in
            print(error)
            textureRequest?.cancel()
        } receiveValue: { (texture) in
            var material = UnlitMaterial()
            material.baseColor = MaterialColorParameter.texture(texture)        
            // Do another setup
            textureRequest?.cancel()
        }
```

What is important there we have to cancel request, to deinit it.
More information you can find in Apple docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/receiving-and-handling-events-with-combine
Or there https://medium.com/@ethansaadia/realitykit-assets-52ada3f9465f